# how to rotate an image in nativescript

Tags: angular, nativescript

I am trying to load an image from local file then rotate it in nativescript. I am currently using imageSource to load the image, but I dont know how to rotate it. If anyone knows there is other class I can use would be also helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to just display the rotated image on screen Or you want to save the image back with updated orientation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you can use [animations](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/animation) this is how I rotate an image in angular project

```
rotate_image() {
    this.circle.nativeElement.originX = 0.5; // default 0.5 (center), 0 is most left, 1 is most right
    this.circle.nativeElement.originY = 0.5; // default 0.5 (middle), 0 is top, 1 is bottom

    this.rotate += ((Math.random() * Math.floor(5)) + 1) * 360;

    this.circle.nativeElement.animate({
        rotate: this.rotate, // will take into account originX and originY
        duration: 1000
    }).then(() => {
        console.log(null);
    }).catch((e) => {
        console.log(e.message);
    });
}
```